# OpenJFX Modular Maven IDE Intellij is not working

Tags: java, maven

Hello I downloaded the sample project HelloFX : https://github.com/openjfx/samples/tree/master/IDE/IntelliJ/Modular/Maven

I followed instructions (Install JDK + OpenJFXSDK + Set JAVA_HOME). But when I run the configuration HELLOFX maven is crashing with the following message:

```
[WARNING] 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init>
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.staticScreen_getScreens(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Screen.initScreens(Screen.java:412)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.lambda$run$1(Application.java:152)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[WARNING] 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline.getAdapterOrdinal(D3DPipeline.java:205)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.assignScreensAdapters(QuantumToolkit.java:695)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runToolkit(QuantumToolkit.java:313)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$startup$10(QuantumToolkit.java:258)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.lambda$run$1(Application.java:153)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Moreover, when I execute `java --module-path %PATH_TO_FX%:target\hellofx-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -m hellofx/org.openjfx.MainApp`, I get the following error message :

```
Unrecognized option: --module-path
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Why this is not working as expected ?

I am using JDK 11.02.